# I want to stop my function from running again, after callbacks. How to achieve that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, return, exit, flipclock

On page load, my countdown clock appears again. I want it never to run again after callbacks are over. I realised that the code I was using ran again on page load.

I have experimented with a `return` and `if` and `else` statements, but I think I am doing something wrong.

```
/*Countdown until Captain Marvel Release */
var next_show = new Date('2019-04-11T12:54:00');
var diff = next_show.getTime() - new Date().getTime();

var showtime = Math.floor(diff/1000);
var clock = $('#clock3').FlipClock({
    clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
    countdown: true,
    callbacks: {
      stop: function () {
        $("#clock3").fadeOut(1000);
        $("#myButton3Show").fadeOut(1000);
        $("#myButton3Hide").fadeIn(1000);
        if(getTime==new Date) { 
          return; //stop the execution of function
      }
      }
    }
});

clock.setTime(showtime);
clock.start();
```

html

```
<div class="captainmarvel2" style="width: 30%">
   <img src="Pictures/captainlogo.png">
   <h5>In Theaters 8 March 2019</h5>
   <div id="clock3"></div>
   <a href="https://www.marvel.com/movies/captain-marvel" target="_blank"
    id="myButton3Show">About Movie</a>
   <a href="https://www.myvue.com/film/captain-marvel" target="_blank" id="myButton3Hide"style="display: none">Buy Ticket on Vue</a>
</div>
```

I want to say IF the date is not 2019 24 April T00.00.00, run the countdown, ELSE hide clock and "About Movie"-button, and show "Buy tickets on Vue".

This is what I am approximately trying to do:

```
var next_show = new Date('2019-04-11T12:54:00');
var diff = next_show.getTime() - new Date().getTime();

var showtime = Math.floor(diff / 1000);
if (next_show.getTime() == new Date().getTime()) {
  $("#clock3").hide();
  $("#myButton3Show").hide();
  $("#myButton3Hide").show();
} else {
  var clock = $('#clock3').FlipClock({
      clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
      countdown: true,
    }
  };

  clock.setTime(showtime);
  clock.start();
```

This is what I am trying now! However, still not working.

You can see the countdowns on www.student.city.ac.uk/~aczc972

[image: Step 1: Counting Down]

[image: Step 2: Countdown Finished - counter and button fade out and new button fade in]

[image: Step 3: On page load, this happens!]

Step 1: Counting Down
Step 2: Countdown Finished - counter and button fade out and new button fade in
Step 3: On page load, this happens!

Comment: `if date = exact date to the minute` will be very limiting - perhaps you mean `if date < exact date`

Comment: Do you mean: `if (new Date() > next_show) $("#clock3").hide();` as the second line of your code?

Comment: I am trying to only execute flipclock if the date is not a specific date. I guess you could use the diff variable and say, if it is more than 0, execute the time?

Comment: You can use localstorage or sessionstorage according to your need for this. set a variable in the callbacks and if its value has been set do not show the countdown clock.

Comment: I tried to use callbacks, but as soon as the page was on load the function was executed again.

Comment: I attached screenshots so you can see what happens when I use callbacks.

Comment: I do not know how to solve this. My experience with javascript is very limited.